# MFMessageComposeViewController - empty recipients and body

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    controller.body = @"Hi! Check out this app i'm using to swap goods!";
    controller.recipients = @[@"0932223223"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Message composer open but recipients and message body are empty (image below).
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IeyQ.png)

Comment: This codes seems right!! make sure that you are confirming `<MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>` and from where you are calling this?

Comment: - (IBAction)inviteFriendButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

Comment: Could it be that you are testing it just on the Simulator instead of a real device?

Comment: No it's real device.

Comment: @hovmush check http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-send-sms-text-message/ and download full code to check the best way of  using MFMessageComposeViewController.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan I had read it. My code is working in another project but not in this.

Comment: your code is working fine at my end too . make sure your viewController confirming theMFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate  like this   ViewController () <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>

Comment: Delegate method is working.

Comment: share your project . Its hard to point the breaking code by provided snippet